# Swapping of subsets in the same list using Python

Tags: python, swap

What's wrong with the code below? I am trying to swap two subsets of list of strings.

```
>>> a = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y']  
['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y']
>>> a[4:9]
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
>>> a[9:10]  
['y']
>>> a[4:9], a[9:10] = a[9:10], a[4:9]
>>> a  
['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two commands executed by your `a[4:9], a[9:10] = a[9:10], a[4:9]`

1. `a[4:9] = a[9:10]` takes the *5th ,6th, 7th, 8th* indices of the list and replaces them with the 9th index. meaning 4 'x' becomes 1 'y' and that leaves you with `['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'y', 'y']` (now the first `y` is the result of your swap, while the 2nd, is just the end of your original list)
2. `a[9:10] = a[4:9]` takes the last index in your list, and swaps it for 5 'x' (that consist the 4:9 indices of original list) resulting in `['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']`

Answer (score -1):

explaination given by @ClsForCookies and here's it's solution you can concate list as below :

```
>>> a
['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y']
>>> a = a[:4] + a[9:10] + a[4:9]
>>> a
['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
>>>
```